# Defining a function to cross-reference variables in 2 dictionaries in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to define a function that allows me to specify a key to cross reference 2 separate libraries. I.e i want to specify the fruit name, and the function to return the cost.

I've looked at some similar code here and copied it but I keep getting a blank return. Not sure where I'm making an error

```
list1 = {"a": "apple", "b" : "banana", "c" : "coconut"}
list2= {"a": 15, "b": 10, "c":5}

def find_fruit_price(fruit, list1, list2):

    for x in list1:
        if fruit in x:
            return list2[x]

    return

find_fruit_price(banana, list1, list2)   # returns a blank output
```

I am expecting "10"

Comment: `"banana"` is a _value_, not a _key_, in the first dictionary, and therefore `if fruit in x` is false.

Comment: `x` is the key, so you should do `if fruit == list1[x]:` instead

Comment: `list1` and `list2` are bad names, because they refer to `dict`s, not `list`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `banana` is an undefined variable.  Use `"banana"` instead.
- `if fruit in x` evaluates as `if "banana" in "b"`, which is going to be `False` for each of your entries.

You need to alter your data logic so that you access and compare the items that might actually match.  For instance

```
if fruit == list1[x]:
```

Comment: Thanks for that clarification! 
So when i do "if fruit in x" , does it just look at the first variable on the dictionary (i.e. a b c)? 
As compared to list1[x], where it looks for the variable associated with the key X?

Comment: Please consult appropriate tutorials and other learning materials for the functionality of basic Python statements.  Stack Overflow is not intended as a tutorial site.